# android: jml library for msn don't work on android 2.1?

Tags: android, msn, jml, instantmessenger

I have managed to connect to msn through jml library on android by adding the getpropertyaction class in my project. 
On android 2.2 works just fine, I can login, get the contacts, send and receive messages and other..

On android 2.1 when I press the login button It doesn't log me in... I don't get any errors in the log (DDMS).. it just stay's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this solution arrive too late:

You can download de code of jml here

```
   http://sourceforge.net/projects/java-jml/files/java-jml/jml-1.0b4/
```

And then apply this patch

```
 http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2910514&group_id=118829&atid=682291
```

(solution found : http://sourceforge.net/projects/java-jml/forums/forum/405891/topic/4093769 )

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it didn't worked in android 2.1